# Trace of executed programs called by a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

A script is misbehaving. I need to know who calls that script, and who calls the calling script, and so on, only by modifying the misbehaving script.

This is similar to a stack-trace, but I am *not* interested in a call stack of function calls within a single bash script.
Instead, I need the chain of executed programs/scripts that is initiated by my script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you say you can edit the script itself, simply put a:

```
ps -ef >/tmp/bash_stack_trace.$$
```

in it, where the problem is occurring.

This will create a number of files in your `tmp` directory that show the entire process list at the time it happened.

You can then work out which process called which other process by examining this output. This can either be done manually, or automated with something like `awk`, since the output is regular - you just use those `PID` and `PPID` columns to work out the relationships between all the processes you're interested in.

You'll need to keep an eye on the files, since you'll get one per process so they may have to be managed. Since this is something that should only be done during debugging, most of the time that line will be commented out (preceded by `#`), so the files won't be created.

To clean them up, you can simply do:

```
rm /tmp/bash_stack_trace.*
```

Comment: That is not a stack trace though. at best it would be a exec trace. But for that <code>pstree -pal</code> or <code>ps -ef --forest</code> would be better suited.<br/>
It doesn’t show the function call *stack*, nor does it show the current code file and line. Which is usually the whole point of a stack trace.

Comment: Yes but OP stated they only wanted to know which scripts call which scripts, so the detail on what lines within the scripts is not necessary. Once you know the exec-stack, you can start adding debug statements like `set -x` to individual scripts for a more fine-grained trace.

Comment: I don't consider this an answer to the question, at least not in the common sense of stack trace.

Comment: akostadinov, it gives every piece of information required by the question which, by the way, called for "something _like_ a stacktrace" and the OP accepted it so they obviously disagree :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, fair enough :)

Answer (score 20):

A simple script I wrote some days ago...

```
# FILE       : sctrace.sh
# LICENSE    : GPL v2.0 (only)
# PURPOSE    : print the recursive callers' list for a script
#              (sort of a process backtrace)
# USAGE      : [in a script] source sctrace.sh
#
# TESTED ON  :
# - Linux, x86 32-bit, Bash 3.2.39(1)-release

# REFERENCES:
# [1]: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID
# [2]: http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc
# [3]: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tac.htm

#! /bin/bash

TRACE=""
CP=$$ # PID of the script itself [1]

while true # safe because "all starts with init..."
do
        CMDLINE=$(cat /proc/$CP/cmdline)
        PP=$(grep PPid /proc/$CP/status | awk '{ print $2; }') # [2]
        TRACE="$TRACE [$CP]:$CMDLINE\n"
        if [ "$CP" == "1" ]; then # we reach 'init' [PID 1] => backtrace end
                break
        fi
        CP=$PP
done
echo "Backtrace of '$0'"
echo -en "$TRACE" | tac | grep -n ":" # using tac to "print in reverse" [3]
```

... and a simple test.

[image: test]

I hope you like it.

Comment: This does not work on Mac OS X. :(  Not that you claimed it did, but just for those who are looking for a Mac solution, this isn't it.

Comment: Yes, it uses Linux facilities (the question was about Linux, after all), sorry...

Comment: This ended up being what worked for me on Mac OS X (and Linux):

    while caller $i
    do
      i=$((i+1))
    done

Answer (score 17):

You can use Bash Debugger http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/

Or, as mentioned in the previous comments, the `caller` bash built-in. See: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/caller

```
i=0; while caller $i ;do ((i++)) ;done
```

Or as a bash function:

```
dump_stack(){
    local i=0
    local line_no
    local function_name
    local file_name
    while caller $i ;do ((i++)) ;done | while read line_no function_name file_name;do echo -e "\t$file_name:$line_no\t$function_name" ;done >&2
}
```

Another way to do it is to change PS4 and enable xtrace:

```
PS4='+$(date "+%F %T") ${FUNCNAME[0]}() $BASH_SOURCE:${BASH_LINENO[0]}+ '
set -o xtrace    # Comment this line to disable tracing.
```

Comment: I especially like this one: i=0; while caller $i ;do ((i++)) ;done

Answer (score 9):

```
~$ help caller
caller: caller [EXPR]
    Returns the context of the current subroutine call.

    Without EXPR, returns "$line $filename".  With EXPR,
    returns "$line $subroutine $filename"; this extra information
    can be used to provide a stack trace.

    The value of EXPR indicates how many call frames to go back before the
    current one; the top frame is frame 0.
```

Comment: While this and `-x` are useful, it sounds like it wouldn't help OP, as this only works on function calls within the same script.

Comment: See Mircea Vutcovici answer above. This one is right what I needed: i=0; while caller $i ;do ((i++)) ;done

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**
The code below should work. Now I have a [newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17734099/520567) with a newer code version that allows a message inserted in the stacktrace.

IIRC I just couldn't find this answer to update it as well at the time. But now decided code is better kept in git so latest version of the above should be in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/akostadinov/33bb2606afe1b334169dfbf202991d36).

**original code-corrected answer below:**

There was another answer about this somewhere but here is a function to use for getting stack trace in the sense used for example in the java programming language. You call the function and it puts the stack trace into the variable $STACK. It show the code points that led to `get_stack` being called. This is mostly useful for complicated execution where single shell sources multiple script snippets and nesting.

```
function get_stack () {
   STACK=""
   # to avoid noise we start with 1 to skip get_stack caller
   local i
   local stack_size=${#FUNCNAME[@]}
   for (( i=1; i<$stack_size ; i++ )); do
      local func="${FUNCNAME[$i]}"
      [ x$func = x ] && func=MAIN
      local linen="${BASH_LINENO[(( i - 1 ))]}"
      local src="${BASH_SOURCE[$i]}"
      [ x"$src" = x ] && src=non_file_source

      STACK+=$'\n'"   "$func" "$src" "$linen
   done
}
```

Comment: Useful bit of code to start with, but it has bugs.  e.g. ${#FUNCNAME[1]} is the length of the first function name not the number of entries in the FUNCNAME array, and the "i - 1" for lineno seems wrong.

Comment: @Eric, thank you, I remember doing some tune-ups in my production version that I can no longer find because I stopped using the thing long time ago. And unfortunately missed to update code here. I fixed `stack_size`. LINENO looks correct to me from a simple local test, let me know if it doesn't work for you. I also remember a difference with `stack_size` when running script from file vs calling some function from interactive shell. I think it can be made auto-guess it but no time to play with it right now. i.e. in interactive, you need `stack_size + 1`.

Comment: @Eric, thanks to you and I could eventually link my two answers on the subject. See update above. Feel welcome to collaborate on the gist. I think that an improvement would be to auto-sense when we need to stop at `stack_size` or `stack_size + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

adding pstree -p -u `whoami` >>output in your script will probably get you the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest script which returns a stack trace with all callers:

```
i=0; while caller $i ;do ((i++)) ;done
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try something like

```
strace -f -e execve script.sh
```