# Does bash support exception?

Tags: bash, exception

Is it possible to raise exceptions in bash? This can be useful, for example, when we want the script to exit when an error happens in a subcommand. Without exception, it seems the best we can do is to append `|| exit` after each subcommand, which gives poor readability.

I didn't find descriptions about exceptions in bash manual. But I'm wondering whether there are ways to simulate them.

Comment: Look for `-e errexit` here http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html

Comment: @heemayl That looks like a feature specifically design for early aborting. However, the script doesn't abort when a non-last command fails in a pipeline (and this is documented). If the command can raise an exception then things would be different.

Comment: @Cyker: You can check a special variable `PIPESTATUS` in `bash` to check if every command on pipe has run properly and break the flow if not running as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Bash does not have a notion of exceptions like other languages like Java have. The key unit of error-reporting in Bash is the [exit code](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html); functions, commands, and scripts all return 0 on success and non-zero to report some sort of error condition. Many programs document specific exit codes to report certain failure modes, for instance `grep` uses `1` to mean no-match-found and `2` to report other errors.

There are a number of useful debugging tricks you can take advantage of despite the lack of exceptions, including the [`caller`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19323/19157) command which enables some introspection of the current execution context.

Other resources:

- [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/113632)
- [Trace of executed programs called by bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/685435/113632)
- [Accessing function call stack in trap function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80476/19157)